# Some WCF Operations require authentication and some don't. How?

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have a WCF Service that requires a username and password.  But not all operations require a username and password.  How is this type of authentication achieved (basically on an operation level)?

Comment: Maybe you can create an additional service where you will put all your operations that don't need authentication

Comment: @boca, is this the only way this can be achieved.  Also, when you say additional service, do you mean a different contract with all operations that don't require authentication.  Can you have multiple services defined?

Comment: Yes. See Richard Blewett answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is performed on an endpoint basis. If you need two authentication models then you will need two different endpoints. The cleanest approach would be to use two separate service contracts

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by clean.  Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe I can have to BasicHttp endpoints in the same service contract?

Comment: If you have two service contracts you need separate endpoint for each of them.

Comment: Well you could in theory use the same service contract on two endpoints and then use authorization to reject the calls that required authentication that had come in on the unauthenticated endpoint. However, your code becomes more complex and your client has a harder job to understand what they need to do